# Intercepting outgoing servlet http requests

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I am working on a school project in which I query and receive some fairly large XML documents from a central server. This was fine in the beginning, as I was rarely making these requests (HTTP GET), but as the project progressed I came up with more things to do with this data, and now I have servlets requesting 3 or 4 XML documents,  each in it's own separate GET request, which is causing upwards of 25 seconds page generation times.

It's not possible to change the way the data is served, neither the way in which it's requested as I have a fairly large code base, and it's not as decoupled as it perhaps should have been.

Is there a smart way to listen in on when my servlets execute these GET requests, intercept them, and perhaps supply them with a local, cached version instead? The data is not THAT volatile, so 'live' data is not needed.

So far, I have not been able to find information on listening on OUTgoing requests made by Tomcat...

Comment: Are these outbound requests doing HTTP requests using native Java libraries?

Comment: Yes, these are done with httpURLConnection. They are not implemented as a servlet but a central .jar that is common to all servlets in my application as they all query the central server

Comment: My initial answer was to suggest using HTTP Client (which has a caching option), but then I realized that you said you couldn't change the way the GET requests were being sent. Instead, see my answer below regarding a caching proxy on your outbound requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot will depend upon your cache hit ratio. If the same 3-4 documents (or some small group of documents) are being requested on a regular basis, a local caching proxy server (like Squid) might be a possibility. Java can be [configured](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) to use a proxy server for HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a shot, I think! Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably implement this using HttpFilter. It can be used as a cache. If requested document is already in cache just return it; if not forward the HTTP request to your servlet.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was not clear. It's not the responses for requests going into my servlet I wish to cache. It's the response (i.e. not generated by me) to MY OWN servlets OUTgoing requests to the central server.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a ContextListener to load most of the data at start-up in addition to an 'expiry date' into the servlet context attributes. It makes for some slow start-ups (9 GetRequests to the central server!) but drastically reduces our page load times.